# Replace `std::vector` with `std::array`

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, c++11

I have a code as follows:

```
int n;

int get_the_number();
void some_computations();

int main()
{
     n = get_the_number();
     some_computations()

     return(0);
}
```

- The `get_the_number` function get some input and returns the integer `n`, which after its call will not be modified.
- In the `some_computation` function there is the following code

  ```
  std::vector<my_struct> my_array;

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  { 
       my_struct struct_temp;

       // fill struct_temp;

       my_array.push_back(struct_temp);
  }
  ```

**Question:** Since the size of `my_array` is known a priori, is it possible to replace the `std::vector` with a `std::array`? 
Moreover, in the affirmative case, should I expect a gain in terms of efficiency?

I tried to replace the vector declaration with

```
 std::array<my_struct,n> my_array;
```

but I get an error: the size of the array must be constant.
Is there a way to avoid it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::array` needs to know the size at **compile time**, which doesn't apply to your code. So no, you cannot simply replace `std::vector` with `std::array` here, unless `get_the_number()` can return a `constexpr` For example.

```
constexpr int get_the_number() { return 42; }

int main()
{
  std::array<int, get_the_number()> a;
}
```

But presumably in your case `int get_the_number()` obtains a number determined at runtime.

Comment: looks like Im not typing fast enough. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast and clear answer. I didn't know about constexpr before: I have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the fact that your array length is a **run time constant** to **improve efficiency**, what you want to do is to use `std::vector::reserve` to **reserve the necessary space** ahead of time to save any reallocations as the vector grows - this should make it almost as fast as an `array`.

```
my_array.reserve(get_the_number());
some_computations()
```

Or if array is local to the function, pass in the number as a parameter.

Comment: The reason `std::vector::reserve`won't be as as fast as `std::array` is that it will be allocated on the heap instead of the stack. A stack allocater for `std::vector` may bring it almost up to `std::array` although it would need to be benchmarked.